# Ходит влево и вправо сайт в браузере samsung

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap

Во всех браузерах сайт работает отлично, но в браузере от самсунг на мобильной версии сайт можно листать ещё влево и вправо где соответственно просто белый фон. Искал и так и не нашёл причин почему так может происходить. Что может быть причиной данного явления?

Comment: В первую очередь, стоит выявить проблему, проверив через https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly и подобными инструментами (Lighthouse вроде тоже умеет). Вопрос в том виде как сейчас, слишком абстрактный... на него невозможно дать точный ответ. Рекомендую уточнить/закрыть, пока он минусов не набрал.

Comment: *Уточнить - в смысле добавить [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, это происходит изза класса .container. Там маргины по 15 пикселей. Надо смотреть вживую,а не гадать на кофейной гущи.